# Sudoku solver performance problems

Tags: performance, prolog, solver, sudoku

I have a problem with my prolog solver for sudoku. It's working, but the performance is reeaaaaly bad. With small ones it's working just fine, but bigger ones like 9x9 or more take 10 minutes or more sadly. I want to leave it for an indefinite size like it is right now. Can anyone help?

```
solve_sudoku(Rows,Sol):-
    length(Rows,Max),
    maplist(same_length(Rows),Rows),
    append(Rows, List), List ins 1..Max,
    maplist(all_distinct, Rows),
    transpose(Rows, Columns),
    maplist(all_distinct,Columns),
    maplist(label,Rows),
    boxes(Boxes,Rows),
    maplist(all_distinct,Boxes),
    boxes_distinct(Boxes),
    Sol = Rows.

boxes(Bs,M) :-
    length(M,Len),
    Sq is round(sqrt(Len)),
    findall(B, (between(1, Sq, R),
            between(1, Sq, C),
            block(M, Sq, R, C, B)), Bs).

cell(M, R,C, V) :-
    nth1(R,M,Row), nth1(C,Row,V).

block(M, Sq, R,C, B) :-
    findall(V, (between(1, Sq, X),
            between(1, Sq, Y),
            I is (R-1) * Sq + X,
            J is (C-1) * Sq + Y,
            cell(M, I, J, V)), B).

boxes_distinct([]).
boxes_distinct([BH|BT]):-
    all_distinct(BH),
    boxes_distinct(BT).
```

The input is a list of lists with the sudoku to solve and the output is the solved sudoku as a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you shoud call

```
maplist(label,Rows)
```

after

```
boxes_distinct(Boxes)
```

usually you should call label or labelling after declaring all constraint.

and use "labeling predicate with ff or ffc option" instead of "label"
may increse efficiency.

Comment: besides above, consider trying 

flatten(Rows,AllVals),
labeling([ffc],AllVals)

instead of

maplist(label,Rows)

because compiling all value in one list let clpfd library choose which variable's domain is narrowed next.

Answer (score 2):

`boxes_distinct(Boxes)` seems useless, being already covered by `maplist(all_distinct,Boxes)`, and use `label(List)` (instead of `maplist(label,Rows)`) near the end of clause. Anyway, the main problem has been indicated by @gabrielte (+1)